# socket_read() not blocking

Tags: php, sockets

Trying to get my socket_read() to block when the data has already been read before.
I need it to wait for the $spawn socket to have new data (can be equal i.e. would like it to read both times when it receives "FE") before it sends again.

**How do I get it to block when there isn't any new data?**

```
$i=0;
while ($i<10){
    //Read and Parse Client input
    $input = strtoupper(bin2hex(socket_read($spawn, 1)));
    echo $input . "\n";

    //Deal with requests
    if ($input == "FE"){ //Server Ping
        socket_write($spawn, $ping_packet);
        echo "Ping Attempt \n";
    } elseif ($input == "02"){ //Handshake Request
        socket_write($spawn, $handshake_packet);
        echo "Handshake Attempt \n";
    } elseif($input == "01"){ //Login Request
        socket_write($spawn, $kick_packet);
        echo "Login Attempt \n";
    }
        $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the socket to be blocking by using [socket_set_block](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-block.php). See [socket_select](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php) for how to handle a large number of sockets at the same time.

Comment: socket_set_block causes my script to either skip the socket_read(), or set it to not block at all.

Comment: I have realised that it is easier for me to learn Node.js and write it in that, than figure this out. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @fiskfisk could you check [this Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360167/tcp-connect-by-using-socket-return-false-results) please? it's about socket and +100 bounty are there! thanks

Answer (score 0):

socket_read will return an empty string if no data is ready to be read. To make a blocking read, use socket_recv with the flag MSG_WAITALL.